# jQuery infinite-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I try to implement basic infinite scroll with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <div>
        <div id="tweets">
            <script>
                for(var j=0; j<=99; j++)
                    document.write(j+'<br/>');
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var start = 0;
        var count = 100;

        $(window).scroll(function()
        {   
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
            {
                start += count;
                for(var i=start; i<=start+count; i++)
                    $('div#tweets').append(i+'<br/>');
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

But it does not work? What can be the problem? Original source is [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)

Comment: seems like working for me, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U9kk4/),
can you specify what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: Try not using document.write.

Comment: @EugenHalca yes your code works, but when I try it in localhost it does not work.

Comment: Do you need to wrap your code in a `$(function(){ });` ready function?

Comment: check if you correctly adding jQuery library to your html file, show your project folder hierarchy and relevant files (html, jquery)

Comment: @EugenHalca I have updated code to contain jquery CDN, it does not work

Comment: @Andy I am trying to understand why it does not work in this way in my localhost, while it works in jsfiddle

Comment: I just tried it on my localhost and it works FWIW.

Comment: @Andy that is the problem that I want to understand :)

Comment: @torayeff -- Check the console!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Try this call to jquery instead: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`. That one of Google's wasn't loading for me.

Comment: @Andy I pasted this code on web here: https://agajan.merkez.biz and it works, what can be problem with localhost

Comment: @tymeJV there is no errors when I check it with firebug

Comment: If you use noscript, do you need to turn it off for localhost?

Comment: @Andy I also found that it does not work in android and iphone. I think I would rather search for some plugin